# Is it possible to use php-memcache and php-memcached together?

Tags: php, memcached

I am moving from php-memcache to php-memcached, but trying to continue using the same cache without completely restarting the memcache servers. Is it possible to do a set with php-memcache and a get with php-memcached?

```
I getting the error - 
int(-1001) string(15) "PAYLOAD FAILURE"

php-memcache
Version - 2.2.7
Revision - $Revision: 327750 $

php-memcached
Version - 2.2.0
libmemcached version - 1.0.18
```

Answer (score 0):

`php-memcache` and `php-memcached` are both wrappers around the system `memcached`  in a similar way that `php-mysql` and `php-mysqli` are both wrappers around the system `mysql`

So yes its possible. You will be able to retrieve the data over telnet also for example http://www.darkcoding.net/software/memcached-list-all-keys/